# How can I access the lock-screen's owner-information of an Android device?

Tags: java, android

I have CyanogenMod installed on my phone in one of the settings menus, it allows me to set some owner information that is displayed on the Lockscreen. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I've seen a lot of questions regarding this but they all seem to confuse the owner information as the "Me" contact on ICS and JB devices. I'm referring to the owner-information as configured in the settings.

Is there a way I can access this information?

Thanks